# Getting a django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table With a Custom User Model

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

Well, I have a custom User Model in an app called accounts. The `accounts.User` looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from accounts.managers import UserManager
from base.models import Model
from accounts.models.profiles import Profile


class User(Model, AbstractBaseUser):
    objects = UserManager()

    phone_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
        message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. 9-15 digits allowed.",
    )
    phone = models.CharField(
        validators=[phone_regex],
        max_length=17,
        blank=True
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True
    )
    staff = models.BooleanField(
        default=False
    )
    superuser = models.BooleanField(
        default=False
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_superuser(self):
        return self.superuser

    def serialize(self):
        data = {
            'id': self.id,
            'email': self.email,
        }
        return data


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

and the `UserManager` looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email')

        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a password')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password):

        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):

        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

And my accounts app registered like this:

```
...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'base',
    'accounts',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

...
```

I run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` and everything run smooth as expected. The problem happen when I start to `python manage.py createsuperuser`. It prompts to give an email input as expected but when typed an email and click enter it returns me an error.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_user
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 117, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).get_by_natural_key(username)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 44, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 397, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 254, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1064, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/zulwiyozaputra/Developer/Environments/poros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_user
```

**What I'm trying is I tried to reproduce the error by deleting the database and doing the migration and I found there is no migration file created in my app as expected because it supposed to have migration file of my custom user created in the database. Anyone had this error before? And how did you resolve it?**

Comment: Remove all files in your migrations folder inside your accounts app except __init__.py. Then try to run migrate again. After that use sqlitebrowser to open the database file created and see if the user table has been created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem solved by manually recreate `migrations/` folder in my app. The folder was deleted when I dropped my Database and Migration Files. The folder doesn't recreated automatically with `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

When creating custom user model from `AbstractBaseUser` you dont need to add Model class as parent, just leave `AbstractBaseUser`:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser)
```

After this clear migrations file and rerun `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem by using AbstractUser. Create these menually field. then add to users

```
id
password
last_login
is_superuser
username
email
first_name
last_name
is_staff
is_active
date_joined
```